# Network Error: expo-app-auth - Broken Request - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, spotify

I'm trying to oAuth through the Spotify api for my React-Native app, but continue to get a `ExpoAppAuth.get Auth: Network Error` message. I'm not understanding what the issue could be, or where in particular to look since the trace is so vague. My clientID and such are correct as well.

```
    `import * as AppAuth from 'expo-app-auth;

    let userData = {
   clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
   additionalParameters: {response_type: 'code', show_dialog: true},
   redirectUrl: 'http://www.google.com',
   issuer: "https://accouns.spotify.com/authorize"
 };

  AppAuth.authAsync(userData)
  .then( data => console.log(data))
  .catch( (error, state) => console.log(`Error: ${error} State: ${state}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the issue at https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/5311 - there is an error in a ternary operator in `expo-app-auth` which will get rolled into an upcoming release. In the meantime, you must specify a dummy value for `registrationEndpoint` in your service configuration object.

Comment: This should be fixed in the latest expo release, per above.

Comment: Hi! Yup, it's the case. Somehow, I was using an old version of the plugin. Thanks!